# Who are the Producers of the Logic EXS24 Sample Libraries?

Tags: logic-pro

Ikutaro Kakehashi is credited with inventing the Roland TR-808 drum machine, which is so significant to the evolution of music over the last few decades.

I don't consider Logic or its EXS24 sampler as significant as the 808, but would love to know the names of some of the folks who created the libraries it comes with.

This [WikiPedia article on Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_Pro) and its roots in Gerhard Lengeling and Chris Adam, C-Lab and Emagic was insightful.

Are there credits somewhere for the folks who create the stock sounds that come with Logic? Maybe in the [manual](https://books.apple.com/us/book/logic-pro-user-guide/id960809726)? Are any of the developers well-known?

Comment: It's been a long time since I was in this business, but a lot of the guys are/were freelancers who traded their talents to the highest bidder. Initially most were German, Hamburg-based*, but that was changing even 20 years ago & is now truly international.  I know guys from as far away as Canada & Japan. I could [but won't;)) give you a few names from back then, but they probably wouldn't mean anything to you. *All the big sequencer/DAW companies were in Hamburg initially. They all knew each other & went drinking together in the evenings.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. So, what exactly is the name of "this business"?

Comment: The 'electronic musical instrument business'. I used to work for Yamaha R&D. I've met most of the Hamburg guys at various trade shows & been over there to visit (& go to the pub;)) many times. I've been using Cubase since it was on Atari & Logic since I was given a pre-release copy by Dr Lengeling himself, in his office. I used & beta tested for most of them across 2 decades. We used to use the same freelancers for many things - really good sound designers get shared around.  I'm still under NDA, so I can never give details.